# SQL Server columnstore clustered index on an indexed view

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2014, indexed-view, columnstore

I want to have an automatically updated structure in SQL Server that can handle aggregate queries well. Can I create an indexed view in SQL server 2014 that has a columnstore index as its clustered index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create a columnstore index on a view as per the documentation:

[CREATE COLUMNSTORE INDEX (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492153.aspx)

In the limitations and restrictions it explicitly states:

> "Cannot be created on a view or indexed view."

Comment: Dude that is specifically for NONCLUSTERED.

Comment: It says nonclustered, but I think that may just be a typo, it is definitely the case that you can't create them, if you try to create a clustered columnstore index on a view you will get the error "The statement failed because a columnstore index cannot be created on a view. Consider creating a columnstore index on the base table or creating an index without the COLUMNSTORE keyword on the view."

Comment: Starting with SQL Server 2016 (13.x), you can create a nonclustered columnstore index on an indexed view.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-columnstore-index-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: That last comment should be the new answer